# GWT file upload java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission

Tags: gwt, file-upload, permission-denied

I have a file upload Servlet and try to store some files as:

```
try{
    File uploadedFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + fileName);
    File uploadedFile = new File("/"+fileName);
    item.write(uploadedFile);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After that I get the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /untitled.html write)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You could either make `/` writable by your app server (which doesn't seem like a great idea to me) or store your uploaded files in another writable location.

```
File uploadedFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + fileName);
File uploadedFile = new File("/"+fileName);
```

You also appear to be trying to declare `uploadedFile` twice. From the error, it looks like either `UPLOAD_DIRECTORY` is `/` or you're actually using the second line. Perhaps you just need to supply the right location in `UPLOAD_DIRECTORY`?

To answer your comment-question about Java policy files:

From [Security and Permissions](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#over) on java.sun.com:

> There is one policy file for Java
>   platform installation (system) and an
>   optional policy file for each user.
>   The system policy file is in
>   {java.home}/lib/security/java.policy,
>   and the user policy file is in each
>   user's home directory. The system and
>   user policy files are combined. So for
>   example,there could be a system policy
>   file with very few permissions granted
>   to all users on the system, and
>   individual policy files granting
>   additional permissions to certain
>   users.

See the [File Permission](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#FilePermission) section for setting file system permissions in the policy file.

And to reiterate my own comment, you'll also want to pay attention to file system permissions in the OS, control of which will depend on the OS you're using.

Comment: I am using eclipse with the Jetty Server, so how can I set the write permission?

Comment: @gwt_user I was thinking of file system permissions, actually. But if you want to change the Java policy file, you could look here: [Security and Permissions](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#FilePermission)

Comment: @IsaacTruett where do I have to put the file in my eclipse project and what do I have to fill in?

Comment: @gwt_user I just updated my answer with more about Java policy files, including the quote from the overview on the page I linked that describes the location of policy files.

Comment: @IsaacTruett with user home directory you mean Users/{User Name} ? I added grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission 
        "<<ALL FILES>>", "read, write, delete, execute";
};
but this does not work? I am using OSX and try to run my app in development mode from Eclipse. What should I do?

Comment: @gwt_user Not to sound like a broken record or anything, but have you checked permissions on the file/directory you're trying to write to? Does the user that the app server runs as have write permission? I'm talking about at the OS level, completely separate from Java.

Comment: @IsaacTruett sure I did, but how can I set the write permissions for the Jetty client that is used by eclipse?

Comment: @gwt_user I don't know what "Jetty client" you're talking about. Do you mean the Jetty server? I would expect that it is running as the same user that Eclipse is running as.